# Why can't I access my own Vue Webpack server via LAN from another device?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm a bit new on this ground, and this is my first question.
I'm asking you, because I couldn't solve this problem for 2-3 days, not even after reading a lot of material around this problem. What I found:

I initialize my vue webpack project like this with using `npm`as `vue init webpack`

After it finishes, I change `host: 'localhost'` to `host: '0.0.0.0'`, and also add `disableHostCheck: true`.

In `config/index.js` dev scope, and I start my server with -> `npm run dev`

Output:

```
Compiled successfully in 3070ms                   
Your application is running here: http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

If I type in my Ipv4 address to the browser with :8080, like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080` my projects is there. It's fine, but I can't see my project from another device, like laptop or mobile phone.

I don't really understand this, because I read that if we type in '0.0.0.0' to the host, it means everyone can get access to the project on LAN.

Could somebody tell me please why is this happening?

Comment: Run your server then issue `netstat -nlp --tcp` and post the output

Comment: Make sure your computer is broadcasting the localhost + port. OS X does it by default, but Windows doesn't

Comment: @4xy sady im using windows and i dont have -nlp command for netstat. But i run netstat with the windows parameters, but i dont saw my server with port 8080. Strange

Comment: @Buffalo every device in the lan has different IP-s, and i forwarded the port 8080, if i understand you corretly

Comment: @TrebitschTheReal For windows try `netstat -a -s -p tcp`

Comment: @TrebitschTheReal Windows firewall will block access to incoming and outgoing ports by default. This Link shows hot to allow other devices in your LAN to access your localhost: https://www.howto-connect.com/allow-ports-firewall-windows-10/
You can also try to turn off the firewall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay guys, i solved this. I will write down the solution, because its so funny and so annoying at the same time when you cant solve something, because of one little thing you dont even think of.

The solution: just enable your ports in the damn windows firewall :D

Now i can host everything, in lan, and public too.

Comment: What application do you need to forward?

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 8080
`
use this to command on ubuntu if you want to open the port

Answer (score 0):

I suppose http://0.0.0.0:8080 available only locally, from machine where your project is running. To see project from another machine (and It should be in the same network it's important) you should obtain your real IP address (you can google how to do it, it depends on OS, on windows use "ipconfig" command in cmd) and then you should see your project in local network on URL which may look like this http://192.168.1.237:8080

Comment: ty. Yes, i use my IPv4 adress to reach my project. Its 192.168.238.104, and if i type this into my browser i see my project. But when i type this for example to my laptop, i get a blank page and "connection timed out". Same network, and there is no ip address collision either. I just dont understand this

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing Base_url from http://localhost:3000 to http://192.168.10.3:3000. My Express App and Vuejs app is both running on the machine with IP address 192.168.10.3. Now on another machine on the same network, the Vuejs app is running and this should send a request to the machine(IP 192.168.10.3) running Expressjs.
Using ipconfig command in the command prompt, machine IP can be determined.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the reason was that port was blocked on my linux.
I first checked which ports are allowed by running the following:

```
sudo ufw status
```

Then I saw that port 8080 was open to specific ip addresses, but it is the Vue web server, so I opened it for all ip addresses with the following:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

You can also open ports 8081, 8082, ... if you have multiple servers running.

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-open-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-linux-12-04-14-04-lts/